# Printing out a triangle in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to write a program to print out a triangle using "*" via methods. I have to design it to ask the user for a number to represent the number of *'s at the base of the triangle.  Then print out the triangle by passing that number to your printUpTriangle() method. The only thing I have an idea about is the actual code to make the triangle which is:

```
public class Triangle {


public static void triangle(int levels) {

if(levels == 0)

return;

triangle(levels - 1);


for(int y = 0; y < levels; y++) {

System.out.print("*");

}

System.out.println();

}
```

I have to write two methods: one to return a String containing n copies of s, concatenated in a row & another one that uses your makeRow() method. It should print a right triangle in which the base of the triangle is made of n copies of s, and the vertex of the triangle has a single copy of s on the right (both methods have an int & String as variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    makeTriangle(5);
    // change the above line if you need to input the number (5) from the user
}

public static void makeTriangle(Integer base_size)
{
    for(int x = 1; x < base_size + 1; x++)
    {
        System.out.print(makeRow(x, base_size));
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static String makeRow(Integer row_num, Integer base)
{
    String row = "";
    for(int x = base; x >= 0; x--) 
    {
        if (x < row_num) { row += "*"; }
        else row += " ";
    }
    return row;
}
```

This makes a triangle with the "vertex of the triangle has a single copy of s on the **right**"

So it will print out

         `*
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two methods, just one toString method.

```
public class Triangle
{
   private int width;

/**
   This class describes triangle objects that can be displayed
   as shapes like this:
   *
   **
   ***
*/
public class Triangle
{
   private int width;

   /**
      Constructs a triangle.
      @param aWidth the number of * in the last row of the triangle.
   */
   public Triangle(int aWidth)
   {
      width = aWidth;
   }

   /**
      Computes a string representing the triangle.
      @return a string consisting of * and newline characters
   */
   public String toString()
   {
      String r = "";
      for (int i = 1; i <= width; i++)
      {  
         // Make triangle row
         for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            r = r + "*";
         r = r + "\n";
      }
      return r;
   }
}
```

And Tester class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
   This program prints two triangles.
*/
public class TriangleRunner
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   { 
      System.out.println("Please enter number");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int i = sc.nextInt();

      Triangle test = new Triangle(i);
      System.out.println(test);
   }
}
```

Comment: Will this work if I have to input a number to determine the number of *'s at the base of the triangle?

Comment: "@param aWidth the number of * in the last row of the triangle." - That means the number you give is the base of the triangle.

Comment: @JohnWalker Added Scanner class so it's easy to play with number of *'s at the triangle base.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Triangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTriangle(10);
    }

    public static String makeRow(int n) {
        return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", "*").replace(" ", "*");
    }

    public static void printTriangle(int n) {
         IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).mapToObj(Triangle::makeRow).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Realized that the OP needed a **RIGHT** triangle. I mistakenly made an equilateral triangle. New output is shown below.

If you really have to have another method to print the triangle:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ICanHasTriangle {

static Scanner input;
static String s = "*";

public static void main(String args[]) {

    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How wide will your base be (Enter an integer): ");
    int width = input.nextInt();

    boolean valid = false;

    while (!valid) {
        if (width <= 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR. You must enter a positive integer!");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Try again: ");
            valid = false;
            width = input.nextInt();
        } else {
            valid = true;
            printUpTriangle(s, width);
        }
    }
}
public static String printUpTriangle(String s, int width) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= width; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {

            System.out.print(s);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
How wide will your base be (Enter an integer): 0
ERROR. You must enter a positive integer!

Try again: 8
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
```

Comment: I just realized I made an equilateral triangle, and you need a right triangle. I skipped Geometry that day. Haha. Back to the drawing board!